# How to use MediaElement from a DataTemplate in the Visual Studio Designer?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, mediaelement

WPF .Net 4.6

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition underlines the "MediaElement" in the DataTemplate with the above warning. There seems to be no problem when running the XAML in either release or debug modes, but the blue underlining is driving me crazy!

How do I fix this?

TIA

Just for reference, the ItemsControl  is bound to a compositecollection in the code-behind:

**C#:**

```
            var d1 = new ObservableCollection<ImageInfo>()
                  {
                    new ImageInfo(){Height=50, Width=double.NaN, Uri= new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Skeleton.png")},
                    new ImageInfo(){Height=50, Width=double.NaN, Uri= new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Female.jpg")},
                    new ImageInfo(){Height=50, Width=double.NaN, Uri= new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Male.jpg")},
                    new ImageInfo(){Height=50, Width=double.NaN, Uri= new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Skeletal Anatomy - Anterior View.png")},
                    new ImageInfo(){Height=50, Width=double.NaN, Uri= new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Male - Front - Nude.png")},
                    new ImageInfo(){Height=50, Width=double.NaN, Uri= new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Male - Back.png")},
                    new ImageInfo(){Height=50, Width=double.NaN, Uri= new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Female - Front.png")},
                    new ImageInfo(){Height=50, Width=double.NaN, Uri= new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Female - Back.png")}
                  };

            var d2 = new ObservableCollection<MovieInfo>()
            {
               new MovieInfo() {Uri = new Uri(@"C:\Nova6\Client\Doctor_Desk\Images\TribeWithFire.wmv", UriKind.Absolute) }
            };

            CompositeCollection data = new CompositeCollection();
            data.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = d1 });
            data.Add(new CollectionContainer() { Collection = d2 });

            ImageCanvasMenu.ItemsSource = data;
```

**XAML:**

```
                        <ItemsControl 
                              Loaded="ImageCanvasMenu_Loaded"  
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                              x:Name="ImageCanvasMenu" Background="LightCyan"  >

                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                  <panels:CustomPanel />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsControl.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ds:ImageInfo}">
                                <Image Height="60" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                                    <Image.Source >
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Uri}"/>
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ds:MovieInfo}">
                                <ContentControl Height="60" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                                    <MediaElement Source="{Binding Uri}" MediaFailed="MediaElement_MediaFailed"
                                     LoadedBehavior="Manual" 
                                     ScrubbingEnabled="True"  
                                     Loaded="Video1_Loaded"             
                                     IsMuted="True"
                                     MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     Stretch="UniformToFill"
                                     />
                                </ContentControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.Resources>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="MediaCenter_PreviewMouseDown"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ItemsControl>
```